# Name of server program which execute scripts

Tags: php

I can't remember the name of the program which executes php scripts by time.

For example:

```
14:00 start new_cache.php
19:00 send_email.php
```

What is the name of this program?

Comment: Which platform? Do you mean cron, or Scheduled Tasks, or Launch Services, or something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you're thinking of [cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron).

For help in using it, see:

- [PHP - good cronjob/crontab/cron tutorial or book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3959099/php-good-cronjob-crontab-cron-tutorial-or-book)
- [How to schedule in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3458350/how-to-schedule-in-php)

Comment: Glad to help. If the answer solved your problem, please remember to accept it as the answer. Thanks.